# How would I create a UIView with two UIWebViews and another UIView and dynamically change the parent UIView size to contain the content views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

I want to have one big view (probably with scroll). It'll show in vertical:

- One HTML string --> 1 webview
- Other HTML string --> 1 webview
- One view with buttons and labels. (fixed size)

I'd want to calculate the heights of the webviews (in webViewDidFinishLoad) for setting the final size of the parent UIView, but in some cases the height of the parent view will be huge so I guess I'll need a scrollview in this case.

What's the best way for doing this?

Comment: Did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Your view structure should look like this.
View Controller -> View -> Scroll View -> View -> All your other stuff.

In your webViewDidFinishLoad method you will want to calculate the height of the content in the UIWebview. Once you have calculated that height set your UIWebview you use that height and reload them. Once the Webview height had been calculated via the content but not applied, you can calculate  the total height of all your other stuff.

Take the height of all your other stuff and apply it to your View just inside the scroll view. For scrolling to work you will need to make sure that your scroll view height is actually smaller than the height of it's contents (the view containing all your other stuff).

Comment: Thanks. Applying this, is it possible to work with storyboards and apply there the constraints so each view is in the right position? What about the heights in this case?

Comment: @nano Yes you can implement everything through storyboards... I do. But when it comes down to adjusting your UIWebView because of content you will need to do it through code. I would suggest putting any static content on top of your dynamic UIWebViews. That way you will have less to adjust positioning for.